# Name error when trying to import API key from .env

Tags: python, django

I am trying to store my API Keys in a .env file

I created the file as a `File containing settings for editor` file type. Stored my APIKeys

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=***
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=***
TWIML_APPLICATION_SID=***
TWILIO_API_KEY=***
TWILIO_API_SECRET=***
```

Installed decouple, imported and used config to retrieve my API tokens in my settings.py file

```
from decouple import config
...
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = config(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID)
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = config(TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
TWIML_APPLICATION_SID = config(TWIML_APPLICATION_SID)
TWILIO_API_KEY = config(TWILIO_API_KEY)
TWILIO_API_SECRET = config(TWILIO_API_SECRET)
```

I am however getting the error message:

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = config(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID)
NameError: name 'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID' is not defined
```

Comment: Should you be passing _strings_ to `config`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the decouple library to read your environment variables.

Firstly download the .env plug-in supporter for PyCharm (if that's what you're using)

https://www.codestudyblog.com/cs2112pyc/1224021812.html

This will allow you to set and get variables from your file. Make sure your configuration has the correct .env file set.

my .env file has the variable set to:

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=SUPER SECRET KEY
```

Then all you need to is:

```
import os

twilio_key = os.environ.get('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')

print(twilio_key)

>>>SUPER SECRET KEY

Process finished with exit code 0
```